# PowerShell Format the output of a function with a label

Tags: powershell

I was wondering if there ia an option to choose your own 'Label' within the part of the code block 'Function'. The script below works just fine, but it's not possible to add something like Label = "Manager".

```
Function Manager ($m)
{ { $m = Get-ADObject -Identity $_.managedBy -Properties displayName,cn
        if($m.ObjectClass -eq "user") { $m.displayName } Else{ $m.cn } } }

$When = ((Get-Date).AddDays(-21)).Date 
        Get-ADGroup -SearchBase "OU=Groups,OU=BEL,OU=EU,DC=domain,DC=net" -Filter {whenCreated -ge $When} -Properties * | 
        Select whenCreated, cn, displayName, GroupScope, GroupCategory, description, info, (Manager managedBy) | Export-Csv "New groups -21 days.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ";" -Encoding utf8; start "New groups -21 days.csv"
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: That's what parameters are for - to input to the function when it's invoked that changes it's behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to format your output table with custom headers and data. 
 `$_` token represents an object passed in the current pipeline which is why it works for the *Select* statement. For that reason you need to change *Manager* so the functions obtains *managedBy* property from the object you pass in, `$u`, as pipelined object `$_` does not exist inside the *Manager* function.

The following changes to *Manager* and your *Select* statement will do it:

```
Function Manager ($u)
 { $m = Get-ADObject -Identity $u.managedBy -Properties displayName,cn
    if($m.ObjectClass -eq "user") { $m.displayName } Else{ $m.cn } } 

$When = ((Get-Date).AddDays(-21)).Date 
    Get-ADGroup -SearchBase "OU=Groups,OU=BEL,OU=EU,DC=domain,DC=net" -Filter {whenCreated -ge $When} -Properties * | 
    Select whenCreated, cn, displayName, GroupScope, GroupCategory, description, info, @{Label="manager"; expression= { Manager $_ } } | Export-Csv "New groups -21 days.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ";" -Encoding utf8; start "New groups -21 days.csv"
```

This is tutorial will help with table formatting
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692794.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I checked that already but somehow I can't seem to put it in my function. Be aware that I'm still a beginner in scripting. I tried the following:

    Function Manager ($m)
{ 
 { $m = Get-ADObject -Identity $_.managedBy -Properties displayName,cn
        if($m.ObjectClass -eq "user") 
   { Format-Table @{Label="Name"; Expression={($m.displayName)}} } 
  Else{ Format-Table @{Label="Name"; Expression={($m.cn)}} } 
 } 
}

Comment: Thank you Raf, this works indeed perfectly! I was only wondering if it was possible to have the label defined in the code block of the function instead of in the select code block. But this works great now, so thank you again for your help.